# Regarding welcome page settings in web.xml for servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have developed an application which contains servlet and few java classes and additionally an html page named home.html which is the opening page..

My web.xml is in this format..

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.saral.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>   
     <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/helloServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 

   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>FirstDemo/WebContent/home.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <listener>
  <listener-class>com.saral.SessionCounter</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Now my query is that after deployment on tomcat the main page get opened is ..
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/835/ie1.png/

but I want this page to be get loaded as first one
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/651/ie3f.jpg/

Please advise me what changes need to be done , so that my opening page becomes correct

Comment: Please do not remove the whole question if you have the answer. Just mark the most helpful answer accepted, or if it had actually a different answer, post your own.

Comment: By the way, what's up with "Regarding" everytime in question titles? Just state a concrete question/statement in there. It's obviously obvious enough that the question title would then regard the concrete question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `home.html` to appear as your home page then just make changes to `welcome-file-list` tag in your web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: No bro you did not get my point..!! I have already done that check my web.xml first

Comment: @user1906154 what exactly do you want?

Comment: I want my first opening page to be set as home.html...http://localhost:9060/FirstDemo/home.html

Comment: could you also please suggest that IF i want validation also like in the both the textboxes value should be there no body can directly hit the generate button without empty textboxes

Comment: @user1906154 that can be easily performed using javascript, just google for "javascript form  validation tutorial" and you will get it.